# Question with answers in wrong order

Tags: support, answers, answer-order

Whoa, something must have gone seriously wrong [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911211/main-thread-hangs-indefinitely-while-waiting-for-nsoperationqueue-operations-to-c) (in terms of answer ordering). Or did I miss something?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you're probably viewing the answers sorted by post time, per the ["oldest" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911211/main-thread-hangs-indefinitely-while-waiting-for-nsoperationqueue-operations-to-c?answertab=oldest#tab-top). I guess you were expecting to see the "votes" tab view.

Note that like the sorting tabs on tag pages, the tab selection for answers is preserved across page views, so if you switched to the oldest tab on a another question that view choice would have carried over.

Comment: i came there via a google link. Lol, I'm on SO for two years now and have never noticed this before.

Comment: Also note that the accepted answer will always be at the top.